# ExtJS 4 - Mark a red asterisk on an required field

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4, required-field

I have this problem where I need to add a red asterisk beside a `fieldLabel` when a field is marked as "required" (or `allowBlank: false`)

In ExtJS3, we can have this hack easily by overriding `Ext.layout.FormLayout` as follow:

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.FormLayout, {
    getTemplateArgs: function(field) {
        var noLabelSep = !field.fieldLabel || field.hideLabel;
        var labelSep = (typeof field.labelSeparator == 'undefined' ? this.labelSeparator : field.labelSeparator);
        if (!field.allowBlank) labelSep += '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>';
        return {
            id: field.id,
            label: field.fieldLabel,
            labelStyle: field.labelStyle||this.labelStyle||'',
            elementStyle: this.elementStyle||'',
            labelSeparator: noLabelSep ? '' : labelSep,
            itemCls: (field.itemCls||this.container.itemCls||'') + (field.hideLabel ? ' x-hide-label' : ''),
            clearCls: field.clearCls || 'x-form-clear-left'
        };
    }
});
```

But this is impossible in ExtJS4. `FormLayout` is no longer applicable, and labels are in fact rendered by `Ext.form.field.Base` by using a mixins called `Ext.form.Labelable`.

Sadly, neither extending the `Ext.form.Labelable` or overriding `Ext.form.Labelable` is workable for me. The extended components from `Ext.form.field.Base` does not receive any effect from it. Even if I swapped the mixins, the templates still would not work.

So here come my solution, where I did a very harsh override over `Ext.form.field.Base`, and it works as follow ([Check out my example](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/Rrv5H/5/))

*This is for ExtJS 4.0.7 only. To use it on ExtJS 4.0.2a you need to modify the `labelableRenderTpl` according to the one found in 4.0.2a `/src/form/Labelable.js`*

```
(function() {

    var overrides =  {
        labelableRenderTpl: [
            '<tpl if="!hideLabel && !(!fieldLabel && hideEmptyLabel)">',
                '<label id="{id}-labelEl"<tpl if="inputId"> for="{inputId}"</tpl> class="{labelCls}"',
                    '<tpl if="labelStyle"> style="{labelStyle}"</tpl>>',
                    '<tpl if="fieldLabel">{fieldLabel}{labelSeparator}</tpl>',
                    '<tpl if="!allowBlank"><span style="color:red">*</span></tpl>',
                '</label>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<div class="{baseBodyCls} {fieldBodyCls}" id="{id}-bodyEl" role="presentation">{subTplMarkup}</div>',
            '<div id="{id}-errorEl" class="{errorMsgCls}" style="display:none"></div>',
            '<div class="{clearCls}" role="presentation"><!-- --></div>',
            {
                compiled: true,
                disableFormats: true
            }
        ],

        /**
         * @protected
         * Generates the arguments for the field decorations {@link #labelableRenderTpl rendering template}.
         * @return {Object} The template arguments
         */
        getLabelableRenderData: function() {
            var me = this,
                labelAlign = me.labelAlign,
                labelCls = me.labelCls,
                labelClsExtra = me.labelClsExtra,
                labelPad = me.labelPad,
                labelStyle;

            // Calculate label styles up front rather than in the Field layout for speed; this
            // is safe because label alignment/width/pad are not expected to change.
            if (labelAlign === 'top') {
                labelStyle = 'margin-bottom:' + labelPad + 'px;';
            } else {
                labelStyle = 'margin-right:' + labelPad + 'px;';
                // Add the width for border-box browsers; will be set by the Field layout for content-box
                if (Ext.isBorderBox) {
                    labelStyle += 'width:' + me.labelWidth + 'px;';
                }
            }

            return Ext.copyTo(
                {
                    inputId: me.getInputId(),
                    fieldLabel: me.getFieldLabel(),
                    labelCls: labelClsExtra ? labelCls + ' ' + labelClsExtra : labelCls,
                    labelStyle: labelStyle + (me.labelStyle || ''),
                    subTplMarkup: me.getSubTplMarkup(),
                    allowBlank: me.allowBlank
                },
                me,
                'hideLabel,hideEmptyLabel,fieldBodyCls,baseBodyCls,errorMsgCls,clearCls,labelSeparator',
                true
            );
        }
    };


    //Both field.Base and FieldContainer are affected, so need to cater for.
    Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, overrides);
    Ext.override(Ext.form.FieldContainer, overrides);


})();
```

And so I have the nice asterisk added to all the required fields.

**Question is, is there any easier way to achieve something like this? Overriding is pretty harsh, best if we can use mixins, but mixins cannot override the behavior**

**Note**

The reason behind this is because I have customized fields that needed to be extended from the base `Text`, `Combo`, `FieldContainer`. [Mixins in the extended field doesn't even mess with the template](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/t9RCr/1/). They are just too stubborn. Perhaps the best way for now is by overriding the Base class... [Check out the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/Rrv5H/5/)

Comment: Good one... That's an issue I will face within the next month, too.

Comment: Thanks. So far this is the only working solution. Mixins doesn't really override the mixins in `Ext.form.field.Base`. I wonder whether there is any better solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have a little bit shorter solution. I suggest to use form's 'beforeadd' event like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
      this.on('beforeadd', function(me, field){
        if (!field.allowBlank)
          field.labelSeparator += '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>';
      });
      this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/2QjyZ/1/)

Comment: I have included your code in my extended Panel and it works great! If there is no better answer then you'll probably get the bounty :) Thou both answers looks great but yours is better since I have already have an extended `form.Panel` in used. Thanks a lot man! Great hack!

Comment: I know that `allowBlank` is only a config and not a property, but in case you set `allowBlank = true` after the component is rendered, this won´t work.

Answer (score 6):

You can still override the layout component similar to extjs3 bun given that there is no fieldLayout, I've overriden `Ext.layout.Layout`. It's quite similar to molecule man's solution but it's more general. Working for fields used in other containers than forms.

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.Layout, {
    renderItem: function(item, target, position) {
      if (item && !item.rendered && item.isFieldLabelable && item.fieldLabel && item.allowBlank == false) {
        item.fieldLabel += ' <span class="req" style="color:red">*</span>';
      }
      this.callOverridden(arguments);
    }
});
```

This is simpler than your solution but not necesarely better, se example also used in fieldsets [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rrv5H/27/)

Comment: Nice! I personaly would also use extending the anchor layout instead of overriding.

Comment: You guys made me hard to decide. I love both answers! Damn! I will credit you guys few days later ok? Both workable but I prefer Molecule as I have extended an custom form panel as well, so most likely I will use his (no need to dirt the js file or open up another js file)

Answer (score 5):

You can also override and extend nothing and just create a controller action like so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    markMandatoryFields: function(field, options) {
        if (field && field.isFieldLabelable && field.fieldLabel && field.allowBlank == false) {
            field.fieldLabel += ' <span class="req" style="color:red">*</span>';
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            "field": {
                beforerender: this.markMandatoryFields
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For **Ext JS 4.1.1** this works:

```
Ext.define('com.ideas.widgets.Base', {
    override : 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    initComponent : function()
    {
        if(this.allowBlank!==undefined && !this.allowBlank)
        {
            if(!this.labelSeparator)
            {
                this.labelSeparator = "";
            }
            this.labelSeparator += '<span style="color:red">*</span>';
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've created a file directly under the app directory, Overrides.js.  I hook it into my app by adding Overrides.js in the require[] array in my app.js file.  Works great, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Yup.. that's how i use it too.. :)

Comment: you can set `labelClsExtra` property instead to be more flexible. I believe that having a css class to identify the labels for required fields is a better approach. I used `this.labelClsExtra = 'x-form-required-field';` and then in the css something like `label.x-form-required-field { text-decoration: underline; }`

Answer (score 4):

Extjs 4.1

When the field has a fieldLabel use:

```
fieldLabel: 'Name',
allowBlank: false,    
afterLabelTextTpl: "<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>"
```

If the field don't have a fieldLabel use a combination of config options, the hideLabel config must be false:

```
//hideLabel: false
name: 'lastName',
emptyText: "Last Name",
allowBlank: false,    
labelWidth: 0,
fieldLabel: '',
hideEmptyLabel: false,
afterLabelTextTpl: '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>'
```

Also, you can mix this solution with Drasill plugin an have a easy way to customise all fields at once.

Answer (score 4):

An approach that you might find more elegant is adding a css class to any field label that is marked with `allowBlank=false` and style your mandatory indicator in CSS.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form', {

    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    listeners: {
        'beforeadd': function(){
            if (!field.allowBlank) {
                field.labelClsExtra = 'x-required';
            }
        }
    }

});
```

You can then style your field label in CSS with an `:after` pseudo utility:

```
.x-required:after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a plugin for this.

Works this ExtJS 4.1 (at least).

Use if like this :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  ...
  plugins : "formlabelrequired"
  ...
});
```

Or, to customize the "asterisk":

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  ...
  plugins : [{ptype:"formlabelrequired", asterisk:" (mandatory)"}]
  ...
});
```

Here is the code for the plugin :

```
/**
 * Plugin (ptype = 'formlabelrequired') that adds "asterisk" to labels
 * for Fields with "allowBlank: false".
 */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.plugin.form.LabelRequired', {

        extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',

        alias: 'plugin.formlabelrequired',

        asterisk: ' <span class="required"> *</span>',

        constructor: function() {

            this.callParent(arguments);

        },

        init: function(formPanel) {
            formPanel.on('beforerender', this.onBeforeRender, this);
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * Adds asterisk to labels.
         */
        onBeforeRender: function(formPanel) {

            var i, len, items;

            items = formPanel.query('[allowBlank=false]');

            for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
                item = items[i];
                item.afterLabelTextTpl = (item.afterLabelTextTpl || "") + this.asterisk;
            }

            return true;

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think using [fieldSubTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-fieldSubTpl) and/or [labelableRenderTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-labelableRenderTpl) to add the * is a cleaner approach than using the event listener. Events can be stopped, listeners can be detached.

I think OP(Lionel Chan)'s concern was that using Ext.override is kinda hacky and he's 100% right. But if we pass the custom tpl in at the form configuration level it's not that bad:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    defaults:{
        fieldSubTpl:['<input id="{id}" type="{type}" ', 
        '<tpl if="name">name="{name}" </tpl>', 
        '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>', 
        '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>', 
        'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off" />',
        '<span>',
        '<tpl if="allowBlank==false">*</tpl>',
        '</span>',
        {
            compiled: true, 
            disableFormats: true
    }]},
    items : [{
        xtype : 'textfield',.....
```

There could be something wrong with the tpl, i haven't tried.

Comment: It is a cleaner aproach, but also a wrong aproach. Setting defaults like fieldSubTpl is wrong because even if they say in the docs that it belongs to Ext.form.field.Base and it has a default value, actualy is overriden in almost any other field classes. As for labelableRenderTpl, we can override the class and modify the tpl or, to just set it into defaluts as base field only takes it form labelable if he doesn't have one defined. But again the issue is that to the labelableRenderTpl the allowBlank data is not sent given that is not considered necesary for the label.

Comment: agreed to both of your points regarding labelableRenderTpl and fieldSubTpl.
I was thinking maybe the right way is to treat the blank state as an error state, somehow style the * using "invalidText" and "msgTarget" . and call "validate" when the field is rendered. so the * will show up because the initial value is invalid.

Comment: no that method is kind of harsh because you will even get red waves rendered under invalid fields and it looks fatal! :)

Comment: haha, true, but we can style that. I guess what I am trying to do is to use as much stock ExtJS as possible while making sure there is a separation of concern between the view and the logic.

Comment: But I still think 4 lines of hack is far more powerful than tons of modifications. My form is defined so there is less permutation over the cancelled events so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to override anything, put the asterisk in the labelSeparator:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  fieldLabel: 'Name',
  name: 'requestor_name',
  allowBlank: false,
  labelSeparator : ': <span style="color:red">*</span>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want red * to be displayed for a field label we can use fieldlabel which does this.

For example the below code creates new text field with label name "Name" and red asterisk is displayed

```
var name = new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel : 'Label<span style=\"color:red;\" ext:qtip=\"This field is required\"> *</span>',
    name : 'name',
    id: 'Name',
    maxLength : 40,
    width : 205,
    allowBlank : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Their are so many ways to do this and few of which you can find above, what I am suggesting is:

```
 {
    xtype : 'label',
    html:'<span>First Name</span><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
    width:50,
 }
```

Simply you can put both asterisk and Label text in single html property.