# How to change required field asterisk in ExtJs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need to change the position of the asterisk indicator of a required field (`allowBlank: false`) to before the field label. Just like the imagem bellow:

[image]

I can't find a proper way in sencha docs.

There a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950375/extjs-4-mark-a-red-asterisk-on-an-required-field) here, but it does not work on ExtJs 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bellow code snippet worked as I wanted to.

```
beforeLabelTextTpl: [
    '<tpl if="allowBlank == false">',
        '<span class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'required">*</span>',
    '</tpl>'
]
```

Comment: nice. any idea how to make this template active after dynamically changing 'allowBlank'? Like when one field gets some value other becomes mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

`afterLabelTpl` and `afterLabelTextTpl` were added in `4.1.0` and should do exactly what you need.

Comment: cool, glad was useful. by the way typically 'required' asterisks goes after the label.

Comment: That is a suggestion of our web designer for acessibility. As her said, the required `asterisk` should come before the label for a screen reader checks first what fields are required.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
    xtype : 'label',
    html:'<span>First Name</span><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); 
    padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
    width:50,
 }
```

Try this out.