# How can i highlight the required fields in yellow in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using `extjs 4.2` and  I want to highlight the required fields in yellow.

This i can do like this

```
.x-form-required-field {

background-color:yellow;

}
```

But what i also want is that if that field is filled then system should remove the highlight

i am not able to do that. can anyone please help me on this

Comment: This post helped me to achieve something similar.(I prefer a simple asterisk) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950375/extjs-4-mark-a-red-asterisk-on-an-required-field

Comment: @code4jhon actually i have that but problem is i want to highlight fields , in big form its diffcult to find stars to see whicgh feilds are required. if input box is highlighted then its easy to spot

Comment: You can find required fields by calling `form.query('field[allowBlank=false]')`. It returns an array that you can iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set emptyText config, then [emptyCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-emptyCls) config can be used

Sample fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5uq