# What causes circled ! in Sencha ExtJS Example?

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the Sencha ExtJS example at this URL:

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#form-contact

Specifically, they show the code but I don't see any place that cause the circled red exclamation point to be drawn whent he field is required.

I'm also wondering if there is a better way to get the red "*" after each field label.  It looks like they repeat the code on every field definition which feels like an anti-pattern to me.

[image]

***UPDATE

Per @CD, this is how to get the red icon

```
       defaults: {
            anchor: '100%',
            labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;padding:0;',
            msgTarget: 'side'
        },
```

Comment: For the DRY pattern, I would recommend a look at the [`defaults`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-defaults) config.

Comment: The error icon is caused by `allowBlank: false`, which makes [`getErrors`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Text.html#Ext-form-field-Text-method-getErrors) method disallow empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error icon have a look at [`msgTarget: 'side'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-msgTarget):

> The location where the error message text should display. Must be one
>   of the following values:
>
> - **qtip** Display a quick tip containing the message when the user hovers
>     over the field. This is the default.
>
>   Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init must have been called for this setting to
>     work.
> - **title** Display the message in a default browser title attribute popup.
> - **under** Add a block div beneath the field containing the error message.
> - **side** Add an error icon to the right of the field, displaying the message in a popup on hover.
> - **none** Don't display any error message. This might be useful if you are implementing custom error display.
> - **[element id]** Add the error message directly to the innerHTML of the specified element.

---

For adding the red "*" try this override:

```
Ext.define('Overrides.form.field.Base', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Base',


    initLabelable: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        if (!this.allowBlank) {
          this.labelSeparator += '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>';
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks @CD  I know we are not suppose to say thank you on SO but I really want to let you know how much I appreciate your posts on my questions.

Comment: I'm curious why you removed the link to the other post.  Is it broken @CD ?

Comment: Also @CD, will the define replace the code in all places or just the form on on?

Comment: @PeterKellner: it was an Extjs4 question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999017  & the override will affect all fields.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "side" attribute in quicktipmanager.  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager

Comment: Have a look at the [`Labelable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-msgTarget) documentation.